# Google Bigquery BQ command line execute query from a file

Tags: google-bigquery

I use the `bq` command line tool to run queries, e.g:

```
bq query "select * from table"
```

What if I store the query in a file and run the query from that file? is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 15):

The other answers seem to be either outdated or needlessly brittle. As of 2019, `bq query` reads from stdin, so you can just redirect your file into it:

```
bq query < myfile.sql
```

Query parameters are passed like this:

```
bq query --parameter name:type:value < myfile.sql
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Also, reminder to people that they may want to use `--use_legacy_sql=false` too.

Comment: This is a great way to initialize schemas :-) Thanks

Answer (score 10):

There is another way.

Try this:

```
bq query --flagfile=[your file with absolute path]
```

Ex:

```
bq query --flagfile=/home/user/abc.sql
```

Comment: this is a massive tip

Comment: Apparently this no longer works `FATAL Flags parsing error: Unknown command line flag 'flagfile'`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323326/using-a-sql-source-file-with-the-bigquery-cli addresses this issue.
If you are on linux you can use 

bq query `cat my_query.sql`

Comment: @Kuan Yao is this documented in the public documentation?  I can't seem to find references to executing a .sql file using the `bq query` command

Comment: This works really well, but I'm not sure it's intended to be used that way for BigQuery. Can you shed any light perhaps @Elliott Brossard i.e is it ok to use this param for passing SQL in a file to BigQuery?

Comment: It works because `--flagfile` tries to extract whatever looks like a flag, and passes the rest to standard input to `bq`. I don't think this will change, but it's kind of a weird hack. Why not just pipe the input from the file instead? `bq query --use_legacy_sql=false < my_query.sql`

Comment: @ElliottBrossard - thanks! We're trying to invoke it from a step in Cloud Build. Our first attempt was to pipe it like you suggest, but it wouldn't work. Also tried back ticks. Maybe this deserves its own question. Agree, using `--flagfile` is hacky.

Answer (score 5):

You can run a query from a text file with a little bit of shell magic:

```
$ echo "SELECT 17" > qq.txt
$ bq query "$(cat qq.txt)"

Waiting on bqjob_r603d91b7e0435a0f_00000150c56689c6_1 ... (0s) Current status: DONE   
+-----+
| f0_ |
+-----+
|  17 |
+-----+
```

Note this works on any unix variant (including mac). If you're using a windows, this should work under powershell but not the default cmd prompt.

Comment: Is there a way to pass parameter values to replace variable names in a query string?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using standard sql (Not Legacy Sql).

```
**Steps:**

1. Create .sql file (you can you any extension).
2. Put your query in that. Make sure (;) at the end of the query.
3. Go to command line ad execute below commands.
4. If you want add parameter then you have to specify sequentially.
```

**Example:**

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=False  "$(cat /home/airflow/projects/bql/query/test.sql)"

for parameter
bq query --use_legacy_sql=False  --parameter=country::USA  "$(cat /home/airflow/projects/bql/query/test.sql)"

cat >/home/airflow/projects/bql/query/test.sql
select * from l1_gcb_trxn.account where country=@country;
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323326/using-a-sql-source-file-with-the-bigquery-cli) thread offers good solution

```
bq query `cat my_query.sql`
```

Comment: is this documented in the public documentation?  I can't seem to find references to executing a .sql file using the `bq query` command

Answer (score 0):

You can run

```
c:\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK>bq query --use_legacy_sql=false < ddl.sql
```

`ddl.sql` file content in multiline,

```
Execute immediate """CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `BQ_PROC.child5_procedure`() 
BEGIN 
CALL `BQ_UTIL.sp_insert_batch_status_log`(0, 0, 'Yoga Test', 'Child 3 called', 'Child 3', 0); 
END;"""
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score -1):

```
bq query --replace --use_legacy_sql=false --destination_table=syw-analytics:store_ranking.SHC_ENGAGEMENT_RANKING_TEST
"SELECT RED,
        DEC,
        REDEM
from `\syw.abc.xyz\`"
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.