# Can I run a query, using BQ command line tool, from a file in Windows command prompt?

Tags: google-bigquery, command-prompt

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33426395/google-bigquery-bq-command-line-execute-query-from-a-file) question, but the answer given was applicable only to Linux/Mac. I know this works in Powershell. Is there a way to do this same thing on Windows using the Command Prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as below

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK>echo SELECT 'Hello' > qq.txt

C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK>bq query < qq.txt
Waiting on bqjob_r56213d80_0000015b20a3b653_1 ... (0s) Current status: DONE
+-------+
|  f0_  |
+-------+
| Hello |
+-------+

C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK>
```

This was run in Google Cloud SDK Shell on Win