# Execute a BigQuery query in Cloud Build step

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-build

I'm using Cloud Build with the `gcloud` builder. I override the `entrypoint` to be `bq` so I can run some BigQuery SQL in my build step. Previously, I had the SQL embedded directly in the YAML config for Cloud Build. This works fine:

```
steps:
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  entrypoint: 'bq'
  args: ['query', '--use_legacy_sql=false', 'SELECT 1']
```

Now I'd like to refactor the SQL out of the YAML and into a file instead. According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33426395/google-bigquery-bq-command-line-execute-query-from-a-file), you can `cat` the file or pipe it to `bq`. This works on the command line without any problems.

But, I can't get it to work with Cloud Build. I've tried lots of different combinations, and escaping chars etc. but no matter what I try the shell doesn't evaluate/execute the `cat my_query.sl` backticks, and instead thinks that it's the query itself:

**Works fine:**
[image]

**Build in Cloud Build it won't work:**

```
steps:
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  entrypoint: 'bq'
  args: ['query', '--use_legacy_sql=false', '`cat my_query.sql`']
```

[image]

I also tried piping it instead of using `cat`, but I get the same error.

I must be missing something obvious here, but I can't see it. I could build a custom docker image, and wrap everything in a shell script, but I'd rather not have to do that if possible.

How do you use Cloud Build with shell evaluation inside a build step?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a custom Bash script, e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "No arguments supplied"
fi
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false < $1
```

Name this `run_query.sh`, then define your steps as:

```
steps:
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: ['run_query.sh', 'my_query.sql']
```

Disclaimer: this is based on reading the docs, but I haven't actually used Cloud Build.

Comment: Thanks for your help Elliott! Yarp, like I mentioned in the question, I was hoping I wouldn't have to drop into a shell script to solve this. But, it looks like it's the only way for now because I can't get it to work directly in the Cloud Build step itself.

Answer (score 3):

I have done this:

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  dir: 'my/directory'
  args: ['-c', 'bq --project_id=my-project-name query --use_legacy_sql=false < ./my_query.sql']
```

Which works with `gcloud builds submit ...` and eliminates one file if you prefer.