# CICD pipeline for Bigquery Schema/ ddl deployment

Tags: google-bigquery, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I am looking for CI/CD solution for the Google Bigquery script.
The requirement is that I have a list of files with DDL script, design the CI/CD solution which should maintain the version, and deploy the script in Google Bigquery in auto/schedule based.

Comment: The goal is control and automate the schema evolutions of `BigQuery` tables ?

Comment: yes, the goal is to commit schema/script in Version control like Github, etc.; after the commit, the new script should execute in Bigquery.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to use version control to commit the schema, you can use CI for Data in BigQuery CLI utility Github Repository which will help you in orchestrating the processes. For more information you can check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/continuous-integration-of-data-in-bigquery#how_to_use_table_clones_and_table_snapshots_to_allow_isolation). For implementing this, you can check this [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ci-for-data-in-bigquery/).

Since you want to use CD, Cloud Build can be used with BigQuery where you can use your own [custom builders](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/use-community-and-custom-builders#using_community-contributed_builders) for your requirement. You can also configure notifications for both BigQuery and GitHub using Cloud Build.

Answer (score 1):

for product recommendation for CI, user cloud source repositories and for CD use cloud build

there are multiple ways to do deploy

option 1: here you are specifying inline query in the cloud build steps, this does not exactly takes into your latest version of SQL. see option 2 for latest version of sql

here you see $PROJECT_ID and $_DATASET these are dynamic variables that you set at run time by environment variables in cloud build also you can use same way to

— name: ‘gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud’
entrypoint: ‘bq’
id: ‘create entry min day view’
args:
— query
— --use_legacy_sql=false
— "CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `$PROJECT_ID.$_DATASET.TABLENAME`
AS
SELECT 1"

option 2:

there is post for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55349260/execute-a-bigquery-query-in-cloud-build-step)

on the last post above link, you can use use bash as entry point and pass bq arguments as args

hope this helps.